# Disk space has dissapeared - after installing Ubuntu desktop

Tags: root, ram, disk-usage

Disc space
I solved this with the help of this post moving data
[Installing all applications on a SSD disk and putting all files on HDD disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk)

I installed Ubuntu from a USB stick and my disc-space disappeared and I believe that windows for whatever reason still is on the hard disk.
I found this solution on the web, but I don't know if it is OK to delete this partition. Can someone help me
I found that I have 3 partitions.
Acer
In partition 3 it stands
Partition 3 Basic data partition
999 GB NTFS
Size 999 GB  (998 997 229 568 bytes)
Contents NTFS — Not Mounted
Device /dev/sda3
Partition Type Basic Data

I had a lot of space on my computer before. But now it tells me low disc space on filesystem root only 316.1 Mg.
Did I accidentally dual boot instead of getting rid of windows or what else went wrong. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: *Did I accidentally dual boot instead of getting rid of windows or what else went wrong* -- Post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: How do you think you "accidentally dual boot"? If you want a user-friendly way to see what is taking up space on your storage, `filelight` is a helpful app that shows your drives as concentric pie charts to show you what takes up the most room.  You should free space before you attempt to install any software. If your root file system completely runs out of space it can cause problems that often require an OS reinstall. Delete large files like videos and music first.

Comment: I haven't used the computer yet so I don't have any files or videos on it. The only thing I have added is a text file

Comment: Hello. You should [post an answer if you solved your problem](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), and not edit your original post with "solved".

Answer (score 0):

I found the lost space on another disk and deleted windows. I then made a new partition and linked my directories from home as suggested by oldfred
[Installing all applications on a SSD disk and putting all files on HDD disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk)
With many thanks it worked.
But I don't know if it is save to move snap also.